# Access variable in aspx.cs file and display in text box

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamic-data

Here is my Emial.Aspx.cs file. I have a public variable called loginEmail.

```
public String loginEmail;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){
loginEmail= Session["Email"].ToString();
}
```

I want to display that variable in bellow textbox. But this is not worked for me.

```
<td>
   <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox_name" runat="server" Text = "<%= loginEmail %>";></asp:TextBox>
</td>
```

Error:

```
Parser Error Message: Server tags cannot contain <% ... %> constructs.
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the page Load event

```
TextBox_name.Text = loginEmail;
```

Comment: Also change `Text = "<%= loginEmail >";` to `Text = "<%= loginEmail %>"`

Comment: gr8. But cant we do this using tags?? Without go to code behind ?

Comment: yes but not as a server control - so   - <input type="text" id="tbn"  value=<%= loginEmail %>/>